# How to start kdiff from Console application?

Tags: c#

UPDATED...

I want to call kdiff from Console application. So I'm building two files and want to compare they at the end of executing my program:

```
string diffCmd = string.Format("{0} {1}", Logging.FileNames[0], Logging.FileNames[1]);
// diffCmd = D:\vdenisenko\DbHelper\DbHelper\bin\Debug\Reports\16_Nov 06_30_46_DiscussionThreads_ORIGIN.txt D:\vdenisenko\DbHelper\DbHelper\bin\Debug\Reports\16_Nov 06_30_46_DiscussionThreads_ORIGIN.txt
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe", diffCmd);

//specification is here http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html
```

It runs kdiff3 tool, but something wrong with filenames or command... Could you please look on screenshot and say what is wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Process.Start()`:

```
string kdiffPath = @"c:\Program Files\Kdiff3.exe"; // here is full path to kdiff utility
string fileName = @"d:\file1.txt";
string fileName2 = @"d:\file2.txt";

Process.Start(kdiffPath,String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"",fileName,fileName2));
```

Arguments as described in the docs: `kdiff3 file1 file2`

Comment: Thats why I added the ", should take care of spaces in filenames I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
var args = String.Format("{0} {1}", fileName, fileName2);
Process.Start(kdiffPath, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run the program from your console app

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = kdiffPath;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + fileName + "\" \"" + fileName2 + "\""; 
p.Start();
```

Unless you are trying to do something else, in which case you need to provide more details.

Comment: Cool, but how to open comparison of two files?

Comment: I suppose that should be the way how to run kdiff3 with set of parameters (filenames) and it should open comparison of two files dialog (not simply kdiff3 tool).

Answer (score 0):

```
string kdiffPath = @"c:\Program Files\Kdiff3.exe"; // here is full path to kdiff    utility
string fileName = @"d:\file1.txt";
string fileName2 = @"d:\file2.txt";    

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(kdiffPath);
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.Arguments = fileName +  " " + fileName2;
Process app = Process.Start(psi);

StreamReader reader = app.StandardOutput;

//get reponse from console app in your app
do
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
}
while(!reader.EndOfStream);

app.WaitForExit();
```